# The joint distribution of $X,Y$ is given by $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(1+x^3y^3)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, transformation

The joint distribution of $X,Y$ is given by $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(1+x^3 y^3)$
Find the joint distribution of $X^2,Y^2$.

I observed that $X,Y \sim \text{Uniform}(-1,1)$
Also, $X,Y$ are not independent as $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{2} \neq f(y)$
The usual approach would be transforming $(X,Y) \rightarrow (U,V) $ where $U=X^2, V=Y^2$
The transformation is not one-one as $X,Y$ can take negative values.
It becomes complicated after that.
Help!

Comment: "It becomes complicated after that." Not really. Simply note that $(U,V)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$ almost surely and compute, for every $u$ and $v$ in $[0,1]$, $$P(U\leqslant u,V\leqslant v)=P(-\sqrt u\leqslant X\leqslant\sqrt u,-\sqrt v\leqslant Y\leqslant\sqrt v)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u, v \in (0,1),$

\begin{align}
P(X^2 \le u, Y^2 \le v) &=P(-\sqrt{u} \le X \le \sqrt{u}, -\sqrt{v} \le Y \le \sqrt{v})\\
&= \int_{-\sqrt{u}}^\sqrt{u} \int_{-\sqrt{v}}^\sqrt{v} f(x,y) \,\, dydx\\
&= \frac14\int_{-\sqrt{u}}^\sqrt{u} \int_{-\sqrt{v}}^\sqrt{v}(1+x^3y^3) \,\, dydx\\
\end{align}

Hopefully you can evaluate the integral.

Comment: The integral comes to be $\sqrt{vu}$ , is it correct?

Comment: congratulations. =)